# lightweight local web server for testing only (windows)

Tags: apache, webserver

i need a lightweight local web server for local testing only.
Like the Mac OS X's WebSharing option, just a simple Apache server setup.
What can you recommend ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not violating the license terms, you can use mongoose web server:

http://cesanta.com/downloads.html

It's very simple to configure and use.